# Help with limits of 2 variables

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I find the following limits? 
$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{\sqrt{xy+1}-1}{xy}$ and 
$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to (2,0)}\dfrac{sin(xy)}{y}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your given term is equivalent to $$\frac{\sqrt {xy+1}-1}{xy}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{xy+1}+1}$$
and write your second term in the form $$\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}\cdot x$$

Answer (score 0):

First,use 
$$\sqrt{xy+1}=1+\dfrac{1}{2}xy+o(xy)$$
so
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{\sqrt{xy+1}-1}{xy}=\dfrac{1}{2}$$

(2):$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,0)}\dfrac{\sin{(xy)}}{y}=\lim_{y\to 0}\dfrac{\sin{2y}}{y}=2$$

Comment: This procedure of using power series expansions is usually 'illegal' in intro courses.